# sum & average different columns in a datatable

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, datatable, datatables

i have a mini project i am working on and have successfully had summing and average work but on different data tables. i would like to have this work in one data table.[sum columns no. of shares & also market price differently..average gain/loss column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIbeN.png)

Unfortunately, i have minimal know how in programming. here is the code:

```
**

 - index.php

**
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <style>
    .company-heading {
      color: #fff;
      background-color: #3c3d41;
      padding-left: 20px;
    }
    .company-heading h1 {
      padding-bottom: 5px;
      font-size: 26px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .company-heading img {
      height: 60px;
      width: 60px;
      padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
    }
    .back-link a {
      color: #3c3d41;
      padding-left: 4%;
    }
    .back-link a:hover {
      color: #800000;
    }
    .font {
      font-family: "Raleway", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; 
    }
    div.dataTables_wrapper div.dataTables_processing {
      background: #a9a9a9;
      color: #fff;
    }
    .pagination > li > a, .pagination > li > span{
      background-color:#515151;
      color:#fff; 
    }
    .pagination > li.active > a, .pagination > li.active > span{
      background-color:#800000;
    }
    .pagination>.active>a,.pagination>.active>a:focus,.pagination>.active>a:hover,.pagination>.active>span,.pagination>.active>span:focus,.pagination>.active>span:hover{
      z-index:3;
      color:#fff;
      cursor:default;
      background-color:#800000;
      border-color:#800000
    }
    .table-content tr:nth-child(odd){
    background-color: #fff;
    }
    .table-content tr:nth-child(even){
        background: #e8e5e5;
    }
  </style>
  <div class="row company-heading">
    <div class="col-sm-2 logo-print">
      <a href="../home/"><img src="../assets/images/libra.png"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <h1>No. of Shares Report</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <h1></h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br> 
  <div class="container box font">
   <div class="table-responsive">
    <table id="order_data_shares" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
      <thead class="table-content">
        <tr style="background-color: #800000;">
        <th style="color: #fff;">Date</th>
        <th style="color: #fff;">Company Name</th>
        <th style="color: #fff;">No. Of Shares</th> 
        <th style="color: #fff;">Market Price</th>
        <th style="color: #fff;">Gain / Loss</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody></tbody>
      <tfoot style="background-color: #800000;">
        <tr>
        <th colspan="2" style="color: #fff;"><strong> Total No. of Shares</strong></th></th>
        <th colspan="1" id="total_order_shares" style="color: #fff;"></th></th>
        <th colspan="2"></th>
      </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 back-link">
      <a href="../home/"><i class="far fa-folder-open"></i> Dashboard</a><br><br>  
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-copyright" style="background-color: #3c3d41;height: 60px;"> 
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
 $(document).ready(function(){

   var dataTable = $('#order_data_shares').DataTable({
    "processing" : true,
    "serverSide" : true,
    "order" : [],
    "language" : {
      "processing" : "Processing Search Request..."
    },
    "ajax" : {
     url:"fetchsearchshares.php",
     type:"POST"
    },
    drawCallback:function(settings)
    {
     $('#total_order_shares').html(settings.json.total);
    }
   });



 });

</script>
```

```
**

 - fetchsearchshares.php

**

<?php

//fetch.php

$connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db", "root", "pass");

$column = array('tarehe', 'doc_type', 'date', 'dateout', 'receive_by');

$query = '
SELECT * FROM transaction 
WHERE tarehe LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" 
OR doc_type LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" 
OR date LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%"
OR dateout LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" 
OR receive_by LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" 

';

if(isset($_POST["order"]))
{
 $query .= 'ORDER BY '.$column[$_POST['order']['0']['column']].' '.$_POST['order']['0']['dir'].' ';
}
else
{
 $query .= 'ORDER BY id DESC ';
}

$query1 = '';

if($_POST["length"] != -1)
{
 $query1 = 'LIMIT ' . $_POST['start'] . ', ' . $_POST['length'];
}

$statement = $connect->prepare($query);

$statement->execute();

$number_filter_row = $statement->rowCount();

$statement = $connect->prepare($query . $query1);

$statement->execute();

$result = $statement->fetchAll();

$data = array();

$toal_order_shares = 0;

foreach($result as $row)
{
 $sub_array = array();
 $sub_array[] = $row["tarehe"];
 $sub_array[] = $row["doc_type"];
 $sub_array[] = $row["date"];
 $sub_array[] = $row["dateout"];
 $sub_array[] = $row["receive_by"];

 $toal_order_shares = $toal_order_shares + floatval($row["date"]);
 $data[] = $sub_array;
}

function count_all_data($connect)
{
 $query = "SELECT * FROM transaction";
 $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
 $statement->execute();
 return $statement->rowCount();
}

$output = array(
 'draw'    => intval($_POST["draw"]),
 'recordsTotal'  => count_all_data($connect),
 'recordsFiltered' => $number_filter_row,
 'data'    => $data,
 'total'    => number_format($toal_order_shares, 2)
);

echo json_encode($output);


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow !

So let's talk about few things.

To be more readable and get more reply on your question, you should focus your code and provide only what we need (we don't need style tag..). Try also to indent your code properly.

You try some code and that's great ! But you don't tell us why isn't working.

After checking out your code, the last `<script>` tag shouldn't be outside the `<body>` tag. By the way, in your PHP, what is `$row['date']` are you sure of your addition ?

Have a look on OOP programming which is a way easier to keep clear code and don't mixed it up.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks D. Schreier!

Apologies for that, i guess that just proves how a newbie i am in this.

i have taken time to understand what you wrote earlier and condensed my problem as below:

i have a data table that has columns and would like to perform calculations on these columns.
i am able to do that with one but unfortunately unable to do with all columns.
i bet my biggest issue is having multiple ajax calls on the same page.This would enable the fetchsearchavg.php file to compute all values and display on the same page. see below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
 $(document).ready(function(){

   var dataTable = $('#order_data_shares').DataTable({
    "processing" : true,
    "serverSide" : true,
    "order" : [],
    "language" : {
      "processing" : "Processing Search Request..."
    },
    "ajax" : {
     url:"fetchsearchavg.php",
     type:"POST"
    },
    drawCallback:function(settings)
    {
     $('#total_order_shares').html(settings.json.total);
    }
   });



 });

</script>
```

all calculations are then performed on fetchsearchavg.php file. I hope you do understand me.
Thanks!